# Weird behaviour when using PHP mysqli row

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I am currently translating a PHP script from a PHP server of version 5.4 to a PHP server with version 5.3

I immediately noticed a wierd behaviour in our login script.

After analysing the script for a bit, I found the source of the problem.

> A call to a member of the first row in $result->fetch_row was invaild.

The declaration of $result is shown below:

```
$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string(strtolower($_POST["USERNAME"]));
$password = $mysqli->real_escape_string(md5(strtolower($_POST["PASSWORD"])));

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
```

By instinct I checked if I had called the data_seek properly, however; I had.

Printing out the fetch_row() function gave me the following result

> Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => admin [2] => d76362b0f640fbcf869033b5e4d1c4bf [3] => Mr [4] => Rasmus [5] => 4 [6] => [7] => 0 )

The array was therefore working.

But the following declaration did not work.

> $Title = $result->fetch_row()[3];

Therefore I tried to store the entire row in a single array object, and then call all sub members individually.

Like so:

```
$row = $result->fetch_row();
$Title = $row[3];
```

And it worked perfectly.

**How come? What is wrong with this declaration:**

> $Title = $result->fetch_row()[3];

Comment: Wrong with which statement?

Comment: Sorry it was a bad formulation. Just corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability to reference the elements of a returned array directly from the calling method is introduced in PHP 5.4 - which is why it's not working in 5.3.

From Example #7 on http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a
>   function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a
>   temporary variable.

So your temporary solution looks like it will become a long-term one :)

Answer (score 3):

You said you were translating the script from PHP 5.4 to PHP 5.3. Apparently you forgot that line because

```
$Title = $result->fetch_row()[3];
```

is not valid PHP 5.3. You should get an error reading:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in ...

[Notes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

Comment: You sir are correct. I just started doing PHP scripting whereas I previously programmed in C#. This is the first time writing in PHP 5.3 - I apologize the trouble.

Comment: No trouble at all. Such problems are not uncommon. I would have provided a link to a changelog if I had found one.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [release notes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) of PHP.net

`functionname()[1]` is something what has been added in PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to dereference the result of a function call directly in PHP 5.3 and later versions but as of PHP 5.4 it is possible